# How to select the group of most recent records based on specific conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to select group of most recent records. I have two tables:

Table1:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+--------+------------------+
| user_id | category_id | field1 | field2 |       date       |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------+------------------+
|      19 |           2 |      3 |      3 | 22/01/2021 15:00 |
|      19 |           1 |      1 |      3 | 22/01/2021 15:00 |
|      19 |           5 |      2 |      2 | 22/01/2021 15:00 |
|      18 |           1 |      2 |      2 | 22/01/2021 15:04 |
|      18 |          31 |      4 |      1 | 22/01/2021 15:04 |
|      18 |          40 |      3 |      1 | 22/01/2021 15:04 |
|      19 |          40 |      2 |      2 | 22/01/2021 15:21 |
|      19 |         166 |      1 |      1 | 22/01/2021 15:21 |
|      19 |          40 |      5 |      5 | 22/01/2021 16:23 |
|      19 |         166 |      6 |      6 | 22/01/2021 16:23 |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

Table2:

```
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|      18 |           1 |
|      18 |          31 |
|      18 |          40 |
|      19 |          40 |
|      19 |         166 |
+---------+-------------+
```

I would like to select the most recent rows from Table1 for specific `user_id` and `category_id` that exist in Table2. For, example if `user_id=19`, I would like to get the following group of records:

```
+---------+-------------+--------+--------+------------------+
| user_id | category_id | field1 | field2 |       date       |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------+------------------+
|      19 |          40 |      5 |      5 | 22/01/2021 16:23 |
|      19 |         166 |      6 |      6 | 22/01/2021 16:23 |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------+------------------+
```

My the most closest query is given the working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/535544/1), but that gives me the last four records of Table1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want for all users:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE T1.DATE = (SELECT MAX(tt1.DATE)
                 FROM Table1 tt1 JOIN
                      Table2 tt2
                      ON TT1.user_id = Tt2.user_id AND
                         tt1.category_id = tt2.category_id
                 WHERE tt1.user_id = t1.user_id AND
                       tt1.category_id = t1.category_id
                )
```

You can add a filter in the outer query for a particular user.

Comment: I don't know how to add that outer query. I have tried just to paste WHERE T2.user_id=19; but this is incorrect syntax.

Comment: @zuriosam After the sub query, after the bracket Add -> AND t1.user_id=19

Comment: @Sudeep Shrestha Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think the most efficient way is using Ties in sql :

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES t1.*
 FROM Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id and t1.category_id=t2.category_id
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.[user_id],t1.[category_id] ORDER BY t1.date desc)
```